# asp.net mvc deployment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, publishing

I've been dealing with a legacy asp.net 2.0 web site that was originally setup to deploy everything (source uncompiled) to the target server. I've been looking at doing some major upgrades and want to move to asp.net mvc.

I'm coming from mostly a Java background where we typically deploy everything inside of a Web ARchive (war file) and the application server takes it from there. Is there a similar concept in the .net world? Right now in my mvc test app, I just put the compiled code into the deployed bin folder and the rest of the script/view files there as well.

From what I have been reading it seems that most use the Publish feature of VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a package and deploy it

http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/02/web-packaging-creating-web-package.html

or you can simply copy the files over

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/06/06/visual-studio-2010-1-click-publishing.aspx

Comment: From the link "To aid all these scenarios we are introducing the concept of  a "Web Package""

So it sounds like MS is -reintroducing- the java WAR file. Thanks for the info, if I can do this without VS 2010 at the moment, I will probably take a look at it. Other than that I think I might just stick with copying the files over.

Comment: You only need to copy your project's binary output to the /bin folder of your site's root. Beyond that you may need to set the root folder to be an application root on the server control panel.

Comment: Well, since I'm using VS2008 right now, I just wrote a python script to copy all the necessary files to the remote server via ftp. I just set an exclusion list of items not to copy. I also have one I run remotely that will copy the entire "Test" data into the live site.